# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when trying to get defined Component

Tags: java, spring, inversion-of-control, preferences

I have a problem with getting a bean from application context when using Spring IoC.

I have a `ContactProvider` interface for my phone book application and 3 implementations of this interface. All implementations are Spring @Components. I also have a `Preferences` which stores which of the implementation is used by the user. When the user tries to change the implementation the application throws NoSuchBeanDefinitionException. To find out which implementation the user wants to use based on his input I created utility enum with all of my implementations that provides `Class` objects for all of the implementation. This class has `fromString()` method which returns implementation type based on given string (which is user input).

Method for setting a new contact provider:

```
private void handleSetProviderCommand(String param) {

        ContactProviders providerType = ContactProviders.fromString(param);
        Class<? extends ContactProvider> providerClass = providerType.getProviderClass();

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        ContactProvider contactProvider = context.getBean(providerClass); // I get NoSuchBeanDefinitionException here
        phoneBook.setContactProvider(contactProvider);

        Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(PhoneBook.class);
        preferences.put(PreferenceKeys.CONTACT_PROVIDER.getKey(), param);
    }
```

ContactProviders enum, from which I take a class of the implementation:

```
    public enum ContactProviders {
        FILE(FileContactProvider.SHORT_NAME, FileContactProvider.class),
        ELASTIC(ElasticContactProvider.SHORT_NAME, ElasticContactProvider.class),
        NO_SQL(NoSqlContactProvider.SHORT_NAME, NoSqlContactProvider.class);

        private final Class<? extends ContactProvider> providerClass;
        private final String shortName;

        ContactProviders(String shortName, Class<? extends ContactProvider> providerClass) {
            this.shortName = shortName;
            this.providerClass = providerClass;
        }

        public static ContactProviders fromString(String param) {
            Optional<ContactProviders> providerType = Arrays.stream(ContactProviders.values())
                    .filter(cp -> cp.getShortName().equals(param)).findFirst();
            if (providerType.isPresent()) {
                return providerType.get();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Contact provider not recognized: " + param);
            }
        }
    }
```

One of the implementations (all of them are annotated with @Component):

```
public class FileContactProvider implements ContactProvider {

    public static final String SHORT_NAME = "file";

    private static final String SEPARATOR = "|";

    private List<Contact> contacts;
    private Path file;
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FileContactProvider.class);

    public FileContactProvider() {
        file = openFile();
        contacts = loadContacts();
    }

    private Path openFile() {
        Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(FileContactProvider.class);
        Path file = Paths.get(
                preferences.get(
                        PreferenceKeys.FILE_FILE_NAME.getKey(),
                        PreferenceKeys.FILE_FILE_NAME.getDefaultValue()
                )
        );
        if (Files.exists(file)) {
            try {
                if (Files.isReadable(file) && Files.isWritable(file)) {
                    return file;
                } else {
                    throw new IOException("The file is not readable or writable.");
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error while opening the file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        } else {
            try {
                Files.createFile(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                logger.error("Error while creating a file: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return file;
    }

    private void saveFile() {
        List<String> contactStrings = new ArrayList<>();
        contacts.stream()
                .sorted()
                .forEach(contact -> contactStrings.add(contact.getName() + SEPARATOR + contact.getNumber()));
        try {
            Files.write(file, contactStrings);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while saving to the file: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    private List<Contact> loadContacts() {
        List<Contact> loaded = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            Files.readAllLines(file)
                    .forEach(line -> {
                        String[] contactString = StringUtils.split(line, SEPARATOR);
                        Contact contact = new Contact(contactString[0], contactString[1]);
                        loaded.add(contact);
                    });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            logger.error("Error while reading file content: " + e.getMessage());
        }

        return loaded;
    }

    @Override
    public Contact save(Contact contact) {
        if (contacts.contains(contact)) {
            System.out.println("Contact is already in the phone book.");
        } else {
            contacts.add(contact);
            saveFile();
        }
        return contact;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> find(String name) throws ContactNotFoundException {
        List<Contact> found = contacts.stream()
                .filter(contact -> StringUtils.indexOf(contact.getName().toLowerCase(), name.toLowerCase()) != -1)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        if (found.isEmpty()) {
            throw new ContactNotFoundException(name);
        }

        return found;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Contact> getAll() {
        return contacts;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Contact contact) {
        contacts.remove(contact);
        saveFile();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure() {
        System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
        String filename = ConsoleUtils.getInput("^[^<>:;,?\"*|/]+$");

        Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(FileContactProvider.class);
        preferences.put(PreferenceKeys.FILE_FILE_NAME.getKey(), filename);

        file = openFile();
        contacts = loadContacts();
    }

    @Override
    public void showConfiguration() {
        Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(FileContactProvider.class);
        System.out.println("File name: " +
                preferences.get(
                        PreferenceKeys.FILE_FILE_NAME.getKey(),
                        PreferenceKeys.FILE_FILE_NAME.getDefaultValue()
                )
        );
    }
}
```

I also have a bean defined in my @Configuration class to provide a contact provider based on preference already set in the system. It takes preference string and creates an instance of implementation class to return:

```
@Bean
    public ContactProvider contactProvider() {
        Preferences preferences = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(PhoneBook.class);
        String preferredProviderName = preferences.get(PreferenceKeys.CONTACT_PROVIDER.toString(),
                ContactProviders.FILE.getShortName());
        try {
            Class<? extends ContactProvider> providerClass = ContactProviders.fromString(preferredProviderName)
                    .getProviderClass();
            Constructor<? extends ContactProvider> constructor = providerClass.getConstructor();
            return constructor.newInstance();
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Can't get provider from given string: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            logger.error("Can't find provider's constructor: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            logger.error("Can't get access to provider's constructor: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            logger.error("Can instantiate provider: " + e.getMessage());
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            logger.error("Can't invoke provider's constructor: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        logger.info("Couldn't get provider from preferences. Default file contact provider instantiated.");
        return new FileContactProvider();
    }
```

Comment: Does your `AppConfig` have Beans for all implementations?

Comment: No, It has only a bean I've posted. The rest of implementations has @Component annotations. I tried to make a bean in config for one of them and the exception was still thrown.

Comment: Are you sure they are in the component scan path?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I resolved this by creating ContactProviderFactory and making it a Spring @Component. Now I get this factory from application context and instantiate needed implementation through factory's methods. It's a solution but It doesn't answer this question so I keep it for now.